# How to convert String to array/object/LIst

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
String str = "[[28.667949,77.287067,232,0,0.8,5],[28.667949,77.287067,232,0,0.8,5]]";
```

I have a String, and want to convert it into any type either in Array,List or Object except String.

Expected Output :

```
 List/Array/Object =
 [[28.667949,77.287067,232,0,0.8,5],[28.667949,77.287067,232,0,0.8,5]]
```

Comment: java is not python, you need to split and convert it

Comment: This is a list of lists not just a simple list. You will have to parse this string in order to convert it into what ever list like object you want. It shouldn't be hard if it is always a list of lists.

Comment: "Array,List or Object", you need to clarify what you want as your end result. Maybe add your code to the question so we understand the context better.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do

```
List ls = Arrays.asList(str.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").split(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is work around for this

1.) First replace all '[' and ']' with ""

```
str = str.replaceAll("[","");
str = str.replaceAll("]","");
```

2.)Then u can split the string with ","

```
which gives u an array.
String[] split = str.split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

If groups of data is important, here's an algo:

```
1. create new List<List<String>> strList
2. String [] strs= str.split("],")
3. loop each str in strs
  3.1 replace all existence of "[" and "]" of str
  3.2 strList.add(Arrays.asList(str.split(",")))
```

Hope this helps!